# Не работает выполнение кода в done после ajax запроса

Tags: javascript, ajax

Браузеры пропускают выполнение кода который указан после done

```
$.ajax({
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": urlWebSite + 'api/basket/deleteItem',
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    "processData": false,
    "data": JSON.stringify({
        "idItem": value[0],
        "itemPrice": value[3]
    })
}).done(function(data) {
    deleteItem(data);
})
```

Сам запрос выполняется корректно, без ошибок. Но не понятно почему браузер пропускает этот код

```
.done(function(data) {
    deleteItem(data);
})
```

Вот сам код вызываемой функции

```
function deleteItem(data) {
    let items = document.querySelectorAll('.main-basket-item');
    for (i = 0; i <= items.length - 1; i++) {
        if (items[i].dataset.iditem == data[0]) {
            let itemPrice = items[i].querySelector('.main-basket-item-price p');
            itemPrice.innerHTML = data[2] + ' р.';
            let itemNum = items[i].querySelector('.main-basket-item-numbers-num');
            itemNum.value = data[1];
            break;
        }
    }
    let basketFull = document.querySelector('.main-basket-confirm-itog h2');
    basketFull.innerHTML = 'Итого: ' + data[3] + ' р.';
}
```

Comment: return deleteItem?

Comment: поставь туда console.log и проверь, может deleteItem не работает

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду в done такое написать? `return deleteItem(data);` . Если да, то так тоже не работает

Comment: Изначально console.log так же пробовал поставить, но в консоль ничего не выводил

Comment: @Sergey да, а делиткаунт возвращает что-то ?

Comment: @grime сама функция ничего не возвращает. Если нужно код самой функции добавлю в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> пропускают выполнение кода

Как Вы это выяснили?

---

У Вас в процессе выполнения `ajax` происходит ошибка и выполнение не попадает в `done`.

```
.fail( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log("ERROR", textStatus, errorThrown);
}.always(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  deleteItem(data);
})
```

Comment: Когда вызываю этот запрос, функция deleteItems не выполняется. В отладчике когда стоит на отметка на done, нажимаю на переход к следующему шагу, дебаггер переходит к коду jQuery, затем следующим шагом становится не содержимое done, а затем выполняет код который после запроса

Comment: @Sergey Что выводится в консоль - `console.log(data);`?

Comment: В консоль ничего не выводится по console.log. Отладчик пропускает код внутри done

Comment: Вполне возможно где-то происходит ошибка. Когда добавили fail, браузер стал выводить синтаксическую ошибку. Но когда оставил always то консоль стал выводить data не то что нужно. Тогда проверю php, что именно должен выводить

Comment: Проблема решена. В самом api коде была ошибка, я не правильно написал переменную, и данные в data не выводились. Извиняюсь, за то что потратил ваше время

Comment: @Smarrti оформите ответом и распишите, в чём именно была ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том, что done не выполнялся по причине того, что получаемый ответ от API был не корректным. Оказалось, что я по случайности опечатался в названии переменной в коде. По этому выводом было не ожидаемые значения, а ошибку. К сожалению я это не проверил.